# $\pi(x)$ Proof Clarification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

In a proof from [a number theory book](https://archive.org/stream/NumberTheory_862/Andrews-NumberTheory#page/n109/mode/2up/search/Prime+Number+Theorem) that $${\pi(x) \over x}\le {2k \over x} + {\phi(k) \over k}$$ 
Where $x=kl+r$ with $0 \le r\lt k $
It is stated that $$\pi(x) \le k+(l-1)\phi(k) + r \le 2k+{x\over k} \phi(k)$$
I understand that the middle counts the maximum number of possible primes not exceeding $x$, but I can't figure out the RHS. Is it obtainable from the middle? If so, can you show how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $0 \leq r < k$, we have $2k > k + r$.
Also, note that $$\frac{x}{k} = \frac{kl + r}{k} = l + {r\over k}$$
which is certainly greater than $(l-1)$.

Therefore, 
$$k+(l-1)\phi(k) + r \le 2k+{x\over k} \phi(k).$$

Comment: Ah thank you, that was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

*This answers the originally posted form of the question. For the edited form, the inequality as rewritten below clearly holds because of $0\le r\lt k$.*

This is not true under the conditions stated. Solving $x=kl+r$ for $l$ and substituting into the inequality leads to

$$r-\left(\frac rk+1\right)\phi(k)\le k$$

This does not hold e.g. for $k=2$, where with $\phi(2)=1$ it becomes $r/2-1\le2$, or $r\le6$, which need not be true.

Comment: I checked the book, and I had the conditions wrong. It is actually $0≤r<k$. Sorry for the inconvenience